# Marker with number in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a scatter plot where some of the values are so close to each other that only one marker is drawn. Is there a way to indicate that there a re more then one entry on this place. I'd like to add a number with items on this location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [datalabels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) and use loop on each series / and each point to check if any points has the same coordinates. Then sum it and return in the funcion.